# Gremlin Traversal Query Language - Mapping query results to java entities

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

I am new to Gremlin query language. Can anyone help with a good tutorial on Gremlin java implementation? I just want to do CRUD operations from java.
 1. Create two Person objects, relation b/w them & its properties and persist in AWS Neptune
 2. Read two person objects from database and output
 3. Update the person object properties
 4. Delete a person object

able to connect to Neptune successfully and execute queries. Looking for java entity mapping query execution and viewing results. and also any visual representation of neptune graph for Gremlin

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, Tinkerpop Frames framework helps in mapping java entities to vertices/edges. However, AWS Neptune supports only "Tinkerpop Gremlin". Tinkerpop Frames can be applied only to "blueprint" graphs whereas AWS Neptune is not one. Hence it is not possible as of now.

Without mapping to Java objects, CRUD operations can be performed using vertices and edges executing queries.